# "Lambda can be replaced with method reference" in Lazy Logging with Log4J2

Tags: java, logging, lambda

I want to make my logging more efficient by using [lazy logging in Log4J2](https://www.baeldung.com/log4j-2-lazy-logging).

This means I'm using lambdas, which are only executed when the log level is correct/fulfilled.

Example:

```
List<Integer> someList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
log.info("Size of list is {}.", () -> someList.size());
```

My IDE tells me, that I can replace this notation with the method reference like so:

```
log.info("Size of list is {}.", someList::size);
```

**My question** is now: Does this approach (method reference) still have the benefit of lazy logging, i.e. that an expensive computational task is only executed in the logging, when the log level is fulfilled or do I lose the whole benefit, when I'm not using lambdas explicitly?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Both the lambda and the corresponding method reference suggested by the IDE end up as an object of the interface type taken by `info()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Log4j2 source code, you will find that the `Logger` class is defining `Supplier<?>` to make it lazy e.g. in one of the [`AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled()` method](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/c83338bff16554d310614c46189c34ed59415415/log4j-api/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/AbstractLogger.java#L1814) you can find:

```
@Override
public void logIfEnabled(final String fqcn, final Level level, final Marker marker, final String message,
            final Supplier<?>... paramSuppliers) {
        if (isEnabled(level, marker, message)) {
            logMessage(fqcn, level, marker, message, paramSuppliers);
        }
}
```

The `Supplier<?>` will only be invoked if the level is enabled, making it lazy.

It makes no difference if you provide the `Supplier` using lambda, method reference or by writing `new Supplier() { }` anonymous class. You can take a look at [Do lambda expressions have any use other than saving lines of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47407180/1602555) question to understand the subtle differences between these approaches, but the bottom line is that they will be lazy.

Comment: Aren't you actually creating an Array of suppliers here. You are also creating the supplier. So two objects are passed even of the logging level is not enabled?